# What's the equivalent of convertToNodeSpace in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, uipinchgesturerecognizer, touch-location

Let me first introduce you to the node hierarchy:

SKView->SKScene->SKNode

I've added a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the view so that I can zoom in and out my content. Here's the code in SKScene object:

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchRecognizer{
    [self runAction:[SKAction scaleBy:pinchRecognizer.scale duration:0]];
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

Everything's OK except for two things:

1. In my node's touch events I check the position of the touch and act accordingly. Everything works fine as long as the scale of the scene is untouched. But if I zoom in or out I can no more do this. It's because even if I seem to touch the same point on the screen it's actually different before and after zooming. In Cocos2D I had exactly the same problem. But I could solve this problem by just converting the touch point to node space with `convertToNodeSpace` method. There should be an equivalent in Sprite Kit. What is it?
2. When pinching, anchor point is the lower left corner. Is there a way to make it zoom from where the pinching occurs?

Comment: there's an API (reference) for that... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint:fromNode:

Comment: Once again Stefen comes for the rescue. I'm aware of convertPoint:fromNode: and convertPoint:toNode: methods but believe me I just can't figure out how to benefit these in order to solve the above mentioned problem.